# Describing all Partial Orderings of a Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question reads: Let A={*a,b,c*}. Use Hasse diagrams to describe all partial ordering on A for which *a* is a minimal element. (There are 10).

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this because I am not told a specific relation. If I am not told a specific relation do I just find the cross products and go through and see what is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive? I know all ten diagrams will have the (a,a)(b,b)(c,c). I am lost from here.

Comment: "*Do I just find the cross products and go through and see what is...*"  No, that would take too long.  There are $512=2^{3\times 3}$ different relations over $a,b,c$.  It is too tedious to actually list out all $512$ of them and go that way.  Instead, do as the problem suggests and instead directly go through the different ways of arranging and labeling Hasse diagrams that represent partial orders here.

Comment: You should be able to see quickly that you have those hasse diagrams shaped like $~~~\mid~~~$    those shaped like $~~\wedge~~$,  those shaped like $~~\vee~~$, those shaped like $\cdot~~\mid$, and finally those shaped like $\cdots$ for a total of $2+2+1+(2+2)+1=10$ different such choices.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh so since I am limited to _a_ being the minimal, I have to build around that criteria?